# finding the output of a c program

Tags: c, structure, output

I'm preparing myself for placement and these days solving C programming questions .
My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct value
    {
        int bit1:1;
        int bit3:4;
        int bit4:4;
    }bit={1, 2, 13};

    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", bit.bit1, bit.bit3, bit.bit4);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm stuck with this structure .
I thought the answer would be : 1,4,4
but the output is : -1,2,-3
Please explain this question.
Thanks.

Comment: There's no union here... Why are you expecting 1,4,4?

Comment: sorry @Chowlett , I made the edits.

Comment: `union`s are very similar to `struct`ures in definition, however, they are very different in implementation!

Comment: yeah ! @Bit Fiddling Code Monkey

Answer (score 3):

What you are observing is sign-extended implicit integer conversion. When converting from a signed smaller integer type to a longer one the compiler will use sign-extended conversion. I.e. The leading bits will be filled with the most significant bit of the smaller type.

Your bitfield `bit1` has only one bit. If you set it to `1` then the most significant bit is set and a sign extended conversion to `int` will lead to `(int)0xFFFFFFFF == -1`.

Same for `bit4` which is 4 bit and initialised with `13 == 0xD` This also has the most significant bit set. Extended to `(int)0xFFFFFFFD == -3`.

If you declare your bitfields as `unsigned int` then you will get zero-extended integer conversion and will observe the output

```
1, 2, 13
```

Answer (score 2):

On compilation it is generating:

```
[Warning] overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
```

and that's why you are getting

```
 -1,2,-3
```

as output.
Note: Always use debugger and debug your program.

Answer (score 2):

This will supply the values of the bitfields:

```
struct value
{
    unsigned int bit1:1;
    unsigned int bit3:4;
    unsigned int bit4:4;
}bit={1, 2, 13};

printf("%d, %d, %d\n", bit.bit1, bit.bit3, bit.bit4);
```

For getting the width of the bitfields, this is not possible...

Answer (score 1):

The :1, :4, :4 is confusing the compiler.  Here is a quick link to the structures.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)

A cleaner programming style is to define the structure separately and instantiate it on another line.

```
/*
  simple1.c - a program to demonstrate c structures.
*/

// Standard libraries
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // Definition
    struct value
    {
        int bit1;
        int bit3;
        int bit4;
    };

    // Instantiation
    struct value bit = {1, 2, 13};

    // Usage
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", bit.bit1, bit.bit3, bit.bit4);

    // All done
    return 0;
}
```